# How to run spark interactively in cluster mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark cluster running on

```
spark://host1:7077
spark://host2:7077
spark://host3:7077
```

and connect through `/bin/spark-shell --master spark://host1:7077`
When trying to read a file with:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
textFile.count()
```

The prompt says

`WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

When checked through Web ui on `host1:8080` it shows:

```
Workers: 0
Cores: 0 Total, 0 Used
Memory: 0.0 B Total, 0.0 B Used
Applications: 0 Running, 2 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Status: ALIVE
```

My question is how to specify cores and memory when running in spark-shell cluster mode? Or I have to run by packaging my scala code into `.jar` file then submit the job to spark?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried: `/bin/spark-shell --master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 7g --executor-memory 7g`?

Comment: @ipoteka I have tried your suggestion. It makes no difference. It seems memory can't be configure in interactive mode

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any workers registered with your master.  You also have different URLs listed above for your master and the spark-shell master setting, but maybe that is a typo.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/29791146/103081

Comment: @Paul My problem was indeed because workers were not registered. And the reason workers not registered was because of mis-configured `conf/slaves` and `conf/spark-default.conf`. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Please package your code using jar and use this in your code

```
    String[] jars = new String[] { sparkJobJar };
    sparkConf.setMaster("masterip");

    sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", sparkWorkerMemory);

    sparkConf.set("spark.default.parallelism", sparkParallelism);
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

Using spark.executor.memory you can provide the worker memory and Parallelism will help with number of parallel tasks running on cluster.

you have slaves file in ../spark/conf you need to put ips from slaves here.

please start master on master node /spark/sbin/start-master.sh

please start slave on slave nodes /spark/sbin/start-slaves.sh