# Spark duplicated workers instantiated

Tags: apache-spark

On the spark master machine, I have the following config in my `conf/slaves`:

```
spark-slave1.com
spark-slave2.com
localhost
```

In `conf/spark-env.sh`, I have

`export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1`

That I intended to have 1 worker from each of the host machine, in total 3 workers, when spark master is started.

Then I start the cluster by: `./sbin/start-all.sh`,

yielding:

```
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to ...
spark-slave1.com: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to ...
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to ...
spark-slave2.com: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to ...
```

Visiting the spark monitorying web interface at localhost:8080 shows **5 workers** registered.

- 1 from localhost
- 2 from spark-slave1.com
- 2 from spark-slave2.com

All of them are having status `ALIVE`

What I have done wrong?

Let me know if any additional information is needed. I changed the hostname for illustration purpose. It is actually a local ip.

**Edit 1 - Added screen capture for reference**
[image]

Comment: On the port 8080 master status page, are workers all reporting `ALIVE` or are some `DEAD`?  Do you have multiple lines per address, or are they simply reporting multiple cores?  There is a worker parameter to control the number of cores launched and memory used.  Maybe you should edit your post to include a picture screenshot of your master port 8080 status page.

Comment: @Paul Thank you for your reply. All workers are `ALIVE`. I'm not sure I understand your other question sorry. I have added a screen cap for your reference.

Comment: Possibly nothing is wrong and somehow the worker script was run twice.  If you can ssh into each slave, you can do a `ps x` or a `pstree` and `kill` the extra slave.  Beyond that, look at the config scripts / what is being run on startup.  If you have [docker](http://docker.com), I have a docker-based spark config described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29791146/103081) and [here too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29712611/103081) and [on dockerhub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/drpaulbrewer/spark-master/).

Comment: @Paul Why are the worker script run twice? And by config scripts, you mean on slave machines' `conf/spark-defaults.conf`? btw, I'm not using docker. Do you recommend using docker for running spark? what is the advantage of using docker for spark?

Comment: Flexibility. I had a few PCs sitting around, but also wanted to be able to tear down / put back the cluster on a moment's notice instead of have a dedicated spark cluster.  Some people would use VMs/vagrant instead, or Amazon EC2 spot with the ec2 script that Spark provides is pretty cheap if you don't have spare PCs or need heavy duty servers.  Unlike a VM, docker runs in a separate compartment with the existing linux kernel and doesn't need to simulate hardware.  So it is lighter in that sense.

Comment: I don't know why your worker script was run twice.  I bring up the possibility, because that is one way to have the worker registered twice.  Quite possibly it will work anyway, but congest the worker with too many tasks leading to poorer performance.  Suggest killing the spare, or rebooting and starting again and seeing if it happens again.

Comment: Make sure to also set SPARK_WORKER_CORES explicitly to limit the cores per worker, or else each worker will try to use all the cores.

Comment: Are you use yarn or mesos? try to login to each of the worker nodes and do jps and see how many worker instance running on each node. And also, how many cores and memory on each workers node?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experienced the some issues, that is because at your configuration file spark-env.sh, you has set multiple worker instances
modify to  `export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1` your problem will solve .